# SharePoint List Item attachment streaming

Tags: custom-list, list-item, video

We are trying to stream videos to a player within our corporative web site, which are stored in list items as attachments. RBS is active in this scenario.In our tests, however, the video its not streammed to the player, but downloaded.

Is it possible to SharePoint to stream the list item attachment to our player ? Storing the videos inside a virtual directory works great, but wanted to manage video permissions through sharepoint.

Alternative sugestion to solve the problem are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found a possible solution for it, even if we are not sure if its the best scenario.

As described in the cenario, attachments only worked with http status 200 (ok). It did not manage to work with partial content (http status 206 partial content). We did the following steps to change it:

1. Transfer all list item attachments to a sharepoint video list
2. Enable BLOB cache on site collection

Thats it. After the file loads up in the front end (as BLOB), our player started working with 206.